# What does the typeid(var_name).name() function returns in C++?

Tags: c++

I used the `typeid(var).name()` function under `#include <typeinfo>` header file and I saw that it returns only a character.

eg.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(5).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(5.8).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
i
d
```

So, it clearly returns character.

Now I'm trying another program where the error coming is:

```
type.cpp:8:46: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     if(typeid((-1 + sqrt(1 - 8 * t)) / 2).name() == 'i')
```

and the program is:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;

    if(typeid((-1 + sqrt(1 - 8 * t)) / 2).name() == 'i')
        std::cout << "YES";
    else
        std::cout << "NO";

    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeid` returns a `std::type_info` object and [`std::type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) returns `const char*` (a pointer). If this `const char*` points to an array containing one character and a `NUL` terminator, it will print the same way as single `char`.

The point is, you can't compare `const char*` with `char`. The function for comaring c-style string (with c-style string) is `std::strcmp`.

But... this is not a use-case for `typeid`. The type of the expression:

```
(-1 + sqrt(1 - 8 * t)) / 2)
```

is known at compile-time and does *not* change at runtime depending on its value. It will be always `float`. Note that you can check types (at compile time) with this:

```
std::is_integral<decltype((-1 + sqrt(1 - 8 * t)) / 2)>::value
```

<sup>The expression within `decltype` does not need to be evaluated (and it can't be) to get the type of an expression.</sup>

**However, you essentially want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521607/check-double-variable-if-it-contains-an-integer-and-not-floating-point).**

Comment: this is helpful. How do we check the expression type at runtime?

Comment: how this `std::is_integral<decltype((-1 + sqrt(1 - 8 * t)) / 2)>::value` is going to help me here?

Comment: @Aryan The type of an expression does not depend on its value. Probably what you mean to do here is to check if the value of `float` is somewhat close to an integer. You should see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521607/check-double-variable-if-it-contains-an-integer-and-not-floating-point).

Answer (score 2):

Member function `name` returns pointer of type `const char *` while you are trying to compare it with an object of type `char` that due to the integer promotion is converted to type `int`.

```
if( typeid((-1+sqrt(1-8*t))/2).name() == 'i' )
                                         ^^^^
                                         char converted to int
```

So the compiler issues an error.

You could use standard function `std::strcmp` declared in header `<cstring>`. For example

```
if( std::strcmp( typeid((-1+sqrt(1-8*t))/2).name(), "i" ) == 0 )
```

However it is implementation-defined what string is generated by the function `name`.

Comment: "However it is implementation-defined what string is generated by the function name." deserves to be highlighted, methinks!