# Check whether a variable is an integral or floating point in C++

Tags: c++

How can I check whether an initialized variable in c++ has integral value or floating point value?

The sample code block is shown below:

```
int main()
{   
    double number = 9.99;

    if (/*Checks whether the value of the 'number' is an integral*/)
        cout << "The 'number' has an integral value";
    else
        cout << "It's not an integral value" // This condition will true if 'number' has a floating point number
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: do you consider 7.0 a integer or a not?

Comment: Use std::modf http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521607/check-double-variable-if-it-contains-an-integer-and-not-floating-point

Comment: What is integral value? Do you mean integer value?

Comment: So if I did wrong with the code, please correct me

Comment: You could use something simple, for example you could do `number == static_cast<int>(number)`. However that have drawbacks like `7.0` being accepted as an integer. Also with the rounding problems of floating point values, a value could be very close to an integer, but not exactly.

Comment: A `double` (or a `float`) is most definitely a floating point number. It will be represented in memory as a float, either in 4 or 8 bytes. It cannot be an integer. If you say `double x = 1;` this cannot be and will not be a `0...01` in memory.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `fmod(number, 1.0)`. If and only if this is *exactly* 0.0 (no epsilon here), then `number` is an integral value.

Comment: Good solution, forgot about this. I'm not sure the caveat you introduced though won't fail here as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#include <typeinfo>

// …
int a = 1;
std::cout << typeid(a).name() << '\n';
```

You could check if `typeid(a).name()` equals either `i` or `int` or whatever else. It depends on your compiler what `typeid(a).name()` is equal to. But you can check it for `int`, `float` and `double` by checking the output so you can make a condition. Hope it helps

Comment: I'm pretty sure the point is assessing whether a float variable is 'integral' in value.

Comment: How is this better than `std::is_integral` ?

Comment: I understood that the question is how to check if a variable is an integer or not (in other words what type of variable it is) so that's why I used this method

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek: Yes, that was clear from your answer, but `std::is_integral` is easier and more portable. It directly tells you true or false; you don't have to guess at strings. (Plus it's compile-time)

Comment: @MSalters except then you would have to provide the type.

Comment: @erichlf: `std::is_integral<decltype(a)>`.

Comment: @MSalters: Yeah, I'm dumb.